# SetContentView for main page

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.forms

In **Xamarin.Android** I can write:

```
SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main);
```

for set the activity content from Main.axml

How I can do the same for **Xamarin.Forms**? How I can move data from Main.axml on main page?

```
Page page = App.GetMainPage();
page.SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main); // page doesn't contain method SetContentView
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should check out Custom Renderers. That is the way we can include platform specific view in Xamarin.Forms. You will need to implement PageRenderer to implement an Activity layout.

Answer (score 0):

A `Xamarin.Forms.Page` is platform independent. You try to call the Android specific method `SetContentView()` on it. That can't work. When you want to set the layout you can either use XAML or set the `Content` of a `ContentPage` in code. 
You can not use AXML Layouts in Xamairn.Forms.

Take a look here: http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/xamarin-forms/getting-started/ and here http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/xamarin-forms/controls/pages/